# Question about Homomorphism and Isomorphism

Tags: group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Does the existence of a homomorphism and a bijection between two groups imply the existence of an isomorphism?

Comment: No.  The group $S_3$ and the cyclic group of order $6$ are in bijection and there is always a trivial homomorphism between any two groups.

Comment: To expand upon the above, the trivial homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\rightarrow H$ is $\varphi(x)=e$, where $e$ is the identity of H.

Answer (score 2):

The answer remains no even if we require a bijection and a monomorphism (injective homomorphism): Consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb C^\ast$ of complex numbers and $\mathbb R^\ast$ of real numbers respectively. They satisfies the stronger requirement by the usual embedding, but are non-isomorphic as they have a different number of roots of unity.